# можно перейти с с# на python?

Tags: python, c#, машинное-обучение

полгода назад начала изучать язык с#, чтобы создавать игры(парочка небольших игр уже созданы), недавно мне показалось, что это не мое, меня больше интересует искусственный интеллект, но так как его пишут на python придется уже учить другой язык. может кто посоветует, можно ли после с# учить питон?

Comment: *можно ли после с# учить питон?* Да что Вы, ни в коем случае! скоро и закон соответствующий выйдет.

Comment: хорошо, на с# можно писать ии?

Comment: `меня больше интересует искусственный интеллект` - поверьте, выучить Python будет наименьшей и пожалуй самой легкой подзадачей :-D

Comment: Успешность написания программ искусственного интеллекта зависит от интеллекта естественного, а вовсе не от изученного языка программирования.

Comment: Это все субъективно. На c# тоже можно писать ИИ, но информации на эту тему на просторах интернета по C# будет гораздо меньше по сравнению с Python. Можете почитать [ответы других людей по вашему вопросу](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/8227).

Comment: это вопрос из серии "можно ли жить, если родился". конечно можно

Answer (score 6):

Вообще-то для `C#` сейчас тоже есть библиотеки для машинного обучения и прочего такого:

- [ML.NET от Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/machine-learning/)
- [Accord .NET](http://accord-framework.net/)

А так я лично после долгого времени работы на `C#` изучил `Python` и мне очень понравилось. Для экспериментов, анализа данных, моделирования `Python` очень удобен и библиотек для него много всяких.

Но по большому счёту инструменты и языки не важны, важно понимать теоретические основы и особенности практического применения, а инструменты всегда найдутся.